# C++ Compilation error about running io_context in different thread

Tags: c++, asio

I am trying to use the asio::io_context in multiple threads.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    asio::io_context ctx;

    std::vector<std::future<asio::io_context::count_type>> tasks;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(&asio::io_context::run, &ctx));
    }

    for(auto &task: tasks){tasks.get();}
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting a compilation error

```
asio_blah.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
asio_blah.cpp:101:94: error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, asio::io_context*)’
         tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(&asio::io_context::run, &ctx));
```

Not sure whey the compiler is not able to figure the member function pointer ( I believe the member func type is `asio::io_context::count_type (asio::io_context*)()` and the function signature should visible to the compiler since asio.hpp is included) and report the error `unresolved overloaded function type`.

Any suggestions to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may go for lambda something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <functional>

using namespace boost;

int main()
{
    asio::io_context ctx;

    std::vector<std::future<asio::io_context::count_type>> tasks;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&ctx]() {
            return ctx.run();
        }));
    }

    for(auto &task: tasks){task.get();}
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

As rightly said by [Miles Budnek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151599/miles-budnek), io_context::run has multiple overloads. You cannot take a pointer to it without forcing overload resolution with a cast.

If you really want to use `std::bind`, go for casting.

My opinion is same as that of others. GO FOR LAMBDA!!!

Comment: Creating an extra function object will work, thanks :) It would be very nice to know why the compiler failed to compile the code.

Comment: @r0ng `io_context::run` has [multiple overloads](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/reference/io_context/run.html).  You cannot take a pointer to it without forcing overload resolution with a cast.  I recommend you forget `std::bind` exists for the most part.  Lambdas work better in almost every situation where it's useful.

Comment: @Miles Budnek, Thanks for your explanation. From the [original asio doc](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html) at the bottom of the page, in the function `main()`, it uses `asio::thread t(boost::bind(&asio::io_context::run, &io));` Is that very diff from what I did?

Comment: @r0ng No, I suspect that example wouldn't compile either.

Comment: @Mils Budnek, Thanks, last question, is the c17 specification explicitly says that std::bind is not able to bind overloaded functions?

Comment: Put Miles's explanation in your answer for an upvote. Don't just dump code!

Comment: @r0ng It's common sense as much as anything else. Which overload should the expression `&asio::io_context::run` bind to? (This isn't a `std::bind` limitation) If you don't tell it, it won't know. Further reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.func http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over And I think you meant C++17, not C17.

Comment: And no the compiler can't "reverse engineer" the correct overload selection based on the other arguments to `std::bind`. Well, it _could_... ironically actually the cast solution to this problem is one of the very rare cases in the language of "things happening backwards"; still, for there to be a special rule for this to happen for one particular _library_ function would be outrageous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Done. Thanks for your suggestion.